# Blocking common.css on Force.com sites to prevent conflict with Bootstrap.css?

Tags: salesforce

Salesforce is injecting commmon.css stylesheets into my pages, causing a conflict with some Bootstrap.css templates I'm using. Is there any way to block the common.css from being injected into my pages? I haven't manually included it anywhere and it's a headache.

Many thanks-

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you try the standardStylesheets attribute of the Page component?

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" />
```

Comment: Perfect- thanks man! You'd think that would come up in a google search- "salesforce common.css block"

Comment: I'm pretty sure it will now :)